# How to convert LocalDate to LocalDateTime in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Hi how can I convert LocalDate to LocalDateTime using `org.threeten.bp`

I have a date 2022-July-27, which is LocalDate, how can I convert to LocalDateTime please

Thanks
R

Comment: FYI, Android supports Java 8 java.time fully through desugaring now, so it's unnecessary to use a backport library. Anyway, just call `atStartOfDay()` or `atTime()` on your LocalDate.

Comment: my app needs to support from minSDKVersion 23, so I cannot use the android ones

Comment: Desugaring makes Java.time available on all SDK versions. https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring